# Multiple "document.getElementById" scripts doesn't work

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, setattribute

Multiple IDs works fine when I'm using HTML #1 but doesn't work when I'm using HTML #2.
Chrome web console shows

`>> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of null ".`

In html#2 I removed

`<div id="0001"><a href="#"">LOGIN</a></div>`, and the browsers do not work anymore.

**HTML #1**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="0001"><a href="#"">LOGIN</a></div>
<div id="0002"><a href="#"">GO</a></div>
<div id="0003"><a href="#"">VISIT</a></div>
<div id="0004"><a href="#"">EXPLORE</a></div>
<div id="0005"><a href="#"">FUNNY PICS</a></div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("0001");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/1.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0002");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/2.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0003");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/3.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0004");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/4.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0005");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/5.html\'');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**HTML #2**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="0002"><a href="#"">GO</a></div>
<div id="0003"><a href="#"">VISIT</a></div>
<div id="0004"><a href="#"">EXPLORE</a></div>
<div id="0005"><a href="#"">FUNNY PICS</a></div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("0001");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/1.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0002");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/2.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0003");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/3.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0004");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/4.html\'');

var element = document.getElementById("0005");
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/5.html\'');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are removing div with id 0001 and then searching for it. Hence it gives the error.

Comment: Wait... you want to use `var element = document.getElementById("0001");...` when the `#0001` does **NOT** exist?

Comment: FYI, posts with titles like SCRIPT DOESN'T WORK - PLEASE FIX IT tend to turn off the SO community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole concept is poor. If you have a link, USE the link. Either directly without script (good for all browsers and for SEO) or change the href or the onclick of the LINK

Also do NOT have numeric IDs

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uGxkt/)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script type="test/javascript">
 var myLinks = [
'http://bing.com/search?q=go',
'http://bing.com/search?q=visit',
'http://bing.com/search?q=explore',
'http://bing.com/search?q=funny%20pics'
]; // note no comma on the last item
window.onload=function() {
  for (var i=0;i<myLinks.length;i++) {
// EITHER    document.getElementById("d"+i).getElementsByTagName("a")[0]).href=myLinks[i];
// OR   
      document.getElementById("d"+i).getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick=(function(idx) {
      var idx = i;
      return function() { // closure 
        location=myLinks[idx];
        return false; // cancel href
      }
    })(i);      
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="d0"><a href="#"">GO</a></div>
<div id="d1"><a href="#"">VISIT</a></div>
<div id="d2"><a href="#"">EXPLORE</a></div>
<div id="d3"><a href="#"">FUNNY PICS</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: leave it plz. but i want to know is there are any script which will store lot of links (thats may be .jpg or .mp3 file) and i can easily insert for download like this - `<div id="Music99"><a href="#"">Download Track # 99</a></div>` just like.. ???

Comment: thanks sir, and try to find out this script too ""i want to know is there are any script which will store lot of links (thats may be .jpg or .mp3 file) and i can easily insert for download like this - `<div id="Music99"><a href="#"">Download Track # 99</a></div>` just like.. ??? ""

Comment: Yes, my script. You store the links in the myLinks and the script will add the href to the link in each div. Alternatively have the script CREATE the div and store an object like `myLinks=[{url:'http....',desc:'description'},....]`

Comment: Hi Sir, Another problem out for that code.
myLinks script works perfect!! but but... 
but the DIVs doesn't work anymore. i mean 
`<div id="d0"><a href="#"">GO</a></div>
<div id="d1"><a href="#"">VISIT</a></div>
<div id="d2"><a href="#"">EXPLORE</a></div>
<div id="d3"><a href="#"">FUNNY PICS</a></div>`
works perfect, but when im trying to change the list EG: 
`<div id="d7"><a href="#"">GO</a></div>
<div id="d5"><a href="#"">VISIT</a></div>
<div id="d11"><a href="#"">FUNNY PICS</a></div>` 
**bold**DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE!**bold** PLz help

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first that element is null or not.

**HTML #2**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="0002"><a href="#"">GO</a></div>
<div id="0003"><a href="#"">VISIT</a></div>
<div id="0004"><a href="#"">EXPLORE</a></div>
<div id="0005"><a href="#"">FUNNY PICS</a></div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("0001");
if(element!=null)
{
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/1.html\'');
}
var element = document.getElementById("0002");
if(element!=null)
{
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/2.html\'');
}
var element = document.getElementById("0003");
if(element!=null)
{
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/3.html\'');
}
var element = document.getElementById("0004");
if(element!=null)
{    
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/4.html\'');
}
var element = document.getElementById("0005");
if(element!=null)
{    
element.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href=\'http://site.com/5.html\'');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```